# How to access the hostname from a new Python module in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am planning to implement a new Ansible module which will run via a local connection and make remote API calls to the host. Is there any way in which I could access the name of the host/IP address from the module? I would like to make a decision on what API to use based on that.

Comment: Can you share more detail. If you are write all API call host into host file. call that host dynamically and use gather facets to get ip address of that host. variable `{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0 }}` give you host ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your doing something like, say, operating on a network appliance from a jump host.

Right now I'm not seeing where you get the inventory_host in the ansiable module base class, but what I often do in this case is:

```
ansible_connection: local
tasks: 
  - name: config net app
    myconfig: action=create_rule host={{inventory_host}}
```

Then make host a parameter of your module.

Then my inventory file might be something like:

```
[firewalls]
host123
host456
host789
```